# How to create hover effect that repels the other links?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a main menu for my website where the links get repelled from the link that is hovered over, as an effect. I got it working when the menu is **horizontal**. But how do I get the links to repel when the menu is **vertical**?

I have tried:
- adding `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, but only the links below get repelled down, while the hovered link itself also is pushed downward.
- adding negative `margin-top` to the hovered link, only pushes itself up.
- adding negative `margin-top` to the link above the hovered.

```css
#MainMenu {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  height: 240px;
}

.MainMenu-Wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

#MainMenu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
}

#MainMenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 2em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="MainMenu">
  <div class="MainMenu-Wrapper">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link4</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried to move the links on hover. Currently I dont see any code related to that feature. Also nothing renders with the provided code so it is very hard to tell what you are going for. Can you update the code or provide any additional info that illustrates what you are going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work but it is still far from perfect. But at least the selectors are doing what they should!

```css
#MainMenu {
  padding: 0;
}

#MainMenu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
#MainMenu li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ddd
}

#MainMenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
}

#MainMenu:hover li {
  top: -20px;
}
#MainMenu li:hover {
  top: 0;
}
#MainMenu li:hover~li {
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="MainMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is essentially what I am trying to achieve, except I can not get it to transition smoothly. My menu is underneath everything. When you press the hamburger-button the screen rotates 45deg inwards and it reveals a menu (horizontal/vertical depending on the screen size). I was hoping to add the same repelling effect to the menu when the screen is small and menu vertical, as when the menu is horizontal. But maybe I don't need it because it mostly would be used on obile where "hover" is not needed (I think).

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure if I understood correctly what you want to accomplish. But is something like [this](http://%20https://playcode.io/362979) what you want?

```css
#MainMenu {
  padding: 0;
}

#MainMenu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
#MainMenu li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ddd
}

#MainMenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
}

#MainMenu:hover li {
  padding-top: 0;
}
#MainMenu li:hover {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="MainMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
</ul>
```